# .htaccess - Remove certain parameters at random positions

Tags: .htaccess, optimization, parameters

I need your help please. **I need to optimize** this as best as possible. Thank you!

X is a random value, but parameter is always "distance" or "type". The "orderBy" parameter with exactly these values.

I need to remove these params:

- orderBy=popular
- orderBy=distance
- distance=X
- type=X

https://example.com/posts/anything?orderBy=distance&distance=400&q=XXX&page=2&type=3&amore=X&another=44
https://example.com/posts/anything?distance=400&q=XXX&orderBy=distance&page=2&type=3&amore=X&another=44
https://example.com/posts/anything?q=XXX&distance=400&page=2&type=3&amore=X&another=44&orderBy=distance

```
# With PARAMETER at the START
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?^distance=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [NE,R=301,L]

# With PARAMETER at the END
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)distance=[^\&]*$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1 [NE,R=301,L]

# With PARAMETER in the MIDDLE
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\&distance=[^\&]*\&(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1&%2 [NE,R=301,L]

# Remove the "orderBy" distance AT THE START
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?^orderBy=distance+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [NE,R=301,L]

# Remove the "orderBy" distance AT THE END
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)orderBy=distance+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [NE,R=301,L]

# Remove the "orderBy" distance in the MIDDLE
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\&orderBy=distance[^\&]*\&(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&%2 [NE,R=301,L]
```

So on..

Comment: I'd start by using alternation for the parts where you have two possibilities, so `orderBy=(popular|distance)`, and `(distance|type)=` I am not sure if non-capturing groups work in the regex flavor supported here, if not you'll probably need to modify the index of the back references used in the substitutions.

Comment: @CBroe can you take a closer look to this matter please? Thank you!